# Pointfree-Style with template-string in ramda.js

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js, pointfree

I've problems writing a pointfree-style function in ramda.js and wondered if anybody can help me with that. The `getEnv` function reads an env-variable and logs to console if it couldn't be found.

Here is my code

```
const env = name => R.path(['env', name], process);

const getEnv = name => R.pipe(
  env,
  R.when(R.isNil, () => log(`Missing env "${name}"`))
)(name);

console.log(getEnv('myenv'))
```

I'd want to drop the `name` parameter of the `getEnv` function (and if possible also on the `env` function) but don't know how to do this.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your problems? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Thanks @FrankerZ . Updated my question recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `getEnv` does more than it should. It actualy *returns the content* of the path **or** *logs a validation message*.

Split it into two separate functions. In my example below, I call it `findPath` and`validatePath`, which works generically for all paths. I've wrapped `validatePath` into another function called`validateEnvPath`, which searches directly for "env"

To get rid of `env` you can do the following: `R.flip (R.curry (R.path))`. This will turn the function curry and then the arguments around, so you can tell the function where you want to query first

```js
const process = {env: {myenv: ':)'}}

const path = R.flip(R.curry(R.path))

const findPathInProcess = R.pipe(
  path (process),
  R.ifElse(
    R.isNil,
    R.always(undefined),
    R.identity
  )
)

const validatePath = path =>
  validationPathResponse (findPathInProcess( path )) (`can't find something under [${path}]`) 

const validateEnvPath = path => 
  validatePath (buildPath (['env']) (path))
  
const buildPath = xs => x =>
  xs.concat(x)
  
const validationPathResponse = response => errorMessage =>
  response
    ? response
    : errorMessage


console.log(validatePath(['env', 'myenv']))
console.log(validateEnvPath('myenv'))
console.log(validateEnvPath('yourenv'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: More than I expected! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `Either` monad. [Sanctuary](https://sanctuary.js.org/) has it already implemented and plays nice with its brother *ramda*:

```
const viewEnv = S.pipe ([
    S.flip (R.append) (['env']),
    R.lensPath,
    R.view,
    S.T (process),
    S.toEither ('Given variable could not be retrieved')
])

const log = R.tap (console.log)

const eitherSomeVar = viewEnv ('someVar')
const eitherWhatever = S.bimap (log) (doSomeOtherStuff)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition one could also write the following

```
const path = R.flip(R.path) // already curried

const findPathInProcess = R.pipe(
  path(process),
  R.when(
    R.isNil,
    R.always(undefined)
  )
)
```